# Quark explanation of reaction

Tags: particle-physics

I've got an issue. There's a reaction in cosmic rays which I need to discuss on 'subatomic' level. I do not need calculations or anything, it has to remain very basic. Could you please explain to me how does this reaction happen on quark level?

$$K^{-} + p^{+} \rightarrow K^{0} + K^{+} + \Omega^{-}$$

I am aware that the $strange$ quark never becomes a $down$ quark and that these mesons and baryons can be written as:

$$\overline{u}s + duu \rightarrow d\overline{s} + u\overline{s} + sss$$

What are the main reactions between the quarks and how to discuss it in Layman's terms?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: To be very specific. I do not need the reactions Feynmann diagram, however that would be useful as well. Thanks again.

Comment: This is a strong interaction  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/omega.html so strangeness must be conserved. You have picked the wrong half of the K0 wavefunction, it should be the anti-s d.  The anti-up of the of the K- with one of the ups of the proton will annihilate to an s-sbar , another s-sbar will come from a gluon , and thus the three sss, and the two  anti s going to the k+ and K0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a famous reaction, that led to the discovery of the $\Omega^-$ baryon.

The quark-line diagram is shown below. The important features are:

- It's all quarks and gluons, no weak bosons or photons, so it's a purely strong-interaction process.
  That means the reaction rate will be relatively large. (Whereas the subsequent decay of the $\Omega^-$ requires a weak-interaction vertex, which is why $\Omega^-$ lives long enough to be observed in a bubble chamber.)
- The diagram is only schematic; it shows the quark rearrangements, and pair creations and annihilations, needed to account for the flavor content of the hadrons. There are many more gluon exchanges, not shown, that bind the quarks into hadrons.
  [image]

Comment: I am really grateful. Exactly what I was expecting.